# Changing whether a service is injected as scoped or transient via the .Net Core DI container at runtime?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

We have several classes that depend on Entity Framework 6 in our application. As such, we inject our `DbContext` into various areas. However, certain modules implement multithreaded methods that require `DbContext` is injected as a transient service to prevent any threading issues. Other modules are capable of being strung together and saved wholesale by simply calling `SaveChanges` on any sub-module or module that receives the same shared `DbContext`. However, this approach requires the `DbContext` be added as a scoped service.

Aside from building some subclass or interface, that simply inherits from my `DbContext`, is there any way to dynamically determine whether a class gets a scoped version or transient version of a given service?

An example of the subclassed context may look something like

```cs
public class TransientDbContext : DbContext {}
public class ScopedDbContext : DbContext {}

// in services
services.AddTransient<TransientDbContext>();
services.AddScoped<ScopedDbContext>();
```

Which works, but I'm looking for something a bit more dynamic where I could potentially pass a parameter to indicate that a class should utilize a shared context.

For some additional context, image I have the following interfaces

```cs
public interface IRepository<TEntity> 
{
    void Add(TEntity entity);
    Task SaveAsync(CancellationToken token = default);
}

public interface IUserManager 
{
    Task AddAsync(User user, bool commitChanges = true, CancellationToken = default);
}

public interface IUserPhoneNumberManager 
{
    Task AddAsync(UserPhoneNumber number, bool commitChanges, CancellationToken token = default)
}
```

And behind the scenes, I may have the follow concrete implementations

```cs
public class UserRepository<User> : IRepository<User>
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
    public UserRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public void Add(User entity) 
    {
        _dbContext.Users.Add(entity);
    }

    public Task SaveAsync(CancellationToken token = default)
    {
        return _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(token);
    }
}

public class UserPhoneNumberRepository<UserPhoneNumber> : IRepository<UserPhoneNumber>
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
    public UserRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public void Add(UserPhoneNumber entity) 
    {
        _dbContext.UserPhoneNumbers.Add(entity);
    }

    public Task SaveAsync(CancellationToken token = default)
    {
        return _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(token);
    }
}
```

Now in some cases, I want the underlying repositories to be injected with a singular scoped context, and other times I want a transient context. Those transient contexts will obviously commit their own changes when used. But the scoped contexts will commit their changes as a singular unit.

Comment: `An example of the subclassed context may look something like` Did that work?

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking for something a bit more dynamic where I could potentially pass a parameter to indicate that a class should utilize a shared context.

Comment: A transient db context doesn't mean that it's thread-safe. It is probably better to make those DAL methods use the db context in a  thread-safe manner or use internal synchronization in your db context classes.

Comment: @swdon In some cases we're performing highly concurrent operations that operate on the database completely independently. (Think running a report and each individual widget on the report is self-executing, self-contained, and ran in parallel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the core of your issue lies in the following observation:

> certain modules implement multithreaded methods that require DbContext is injected as a transient service to prevent any threading issues.

This implies that your application code itself is responsible for handling multi-threadedness; you are likely starting new threads or tasks. This is something you should prevent.

Instead, only your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) should know about multitheadedness and should spin off new threads. This centralizes the knowledge around thread safety. But not only that, but many components are not thread-safe and *only* the Composition Root should be aware of which components are and aren't. A component itself, should always just call its dependencies in a sequential way and assume there is just a single instance of that dependency.

This means that when you are starting parallel operations, you should go back to the Composition Root to let it resolve a new object graph. The Composition Root could then decide to inject new instances of components into the graph (for instance your `DbContext`).

When you apply this way of working, you won't need to have a transient and a scoped version of your `DbContext` any longer.

For more information, see: [working with DI in multi-threaded applications](https://simpleinjector.org/howto#work-with-dependency-injection-in-multi-threaded-applications). My book [DI PP&P](https://mng.bz/BYNl) does contain some material explaining this.

Comment: You're mostly correct. We have 2 separate use-cases where we've needed to dynamically spin up database contexts. In one case, we're performing highly concurrent operations that need to save information to the `DbContext` repeatedly. When sharing a single context to do this, we run into issues. The second case is multiple concurrent async saves that do not need to complete in any specific order. However, we receive concurrency exceptions from EF6 if these calls aren't waited individually (instead of doing it as a batch).

Comment: Other than that, we have certain classes implementing `IRepository<TEntity>` which contains a `SaveAsync` method. If we want to perform multiple operations and then save the batch, we simply need to call `SaveAsync` in one repository and all repositories sharing that same scoped context get saved as well.

Comment: I took a peek at your site. In your opinion, would building a proxy that either supplies a scoped or transient context based on the use-case be the proper approach here? I updated the original question with more details.